# Process Specific Range Row During Insert CSV file in MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data from csv to MYSQL database like below and its working fine

```
$file = fopen('../assets/uploads/'.$file_name, "r");
            
            while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            
            $fname = "";
            if (isset($column[0])) {
                $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $column[0]);
            }
            $lname = "";
            if (isset($column[1])) {
                $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $column[1]);
            }
            $email = "";
            if (isset($column[2])) {
                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $column[2]);
            }
            
            
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT into $lead_data_table (lfname,llname,lemail,lead_id,lead_user_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlInsert);
            $stmt->bind_param('sssii', $fname, $lname,$email,$lead_insert_id,$lead_user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            
           $insertId = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
```

However For some reason `I want insert data from CSV like 0 to 100 or 100 to Remain All`. I am not getting idea how I can do it? Let me know if anyone here can help me for do the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the csv lines and skip. Something like this will process starting with the hundredth line.

```php
$file = fopen('../assets/uploads/'.$file_name, "r");
$lineCount = 0;
while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $lineCount ++;
    if ($lineCount >= 100) {
        /* process the line */
    }
}
```

And by the way, you're doing your prepared statements correctly. So you don't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to mung your data before inserting it.